# How to Get JQuery UI Droppable to Drop Multiple Elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have been given a piece of code that allows the user to drag one row of a table to a div. I have been asked to allow the user to select multiple rows and drag them all to the div. I've been trying to modify the code I was given to do what I need it to do.

So, I have a table of rows, where the first column of each row contains a drop down box. I want the user to be able to select many check-boxes, and be able to drag all the rows corresponding to those checked check-boxes into another containing a table.

I managed to get the dragging part to work - the user is able to check many check-boxes, and its shows a group of rows being dragged. However, when I drop these rows, only one row in being dropped. Can anyone help me drop all the rows being dragged. Here is my code:

```
$(oTable.fnGetNodes()).draggable({
    appendTo: "#event",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: function (event) {
        var checkBoxes = $(".drag");
        var rows = $('#lotsDataTable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)');

        if (checkBoxes.length > 0) {
            return $('<div class="dragContainer"><table></table></div>').find('table').append(rows.clone()).appendTo('#event');
        } else {
            return $('<div class="dragContainer"><table></table></div>').find('table').append($(event.target).closest('tr').clone()).appendTo('#event');
        }
    }
});

$("#event table").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not()",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        $("<tr></tr>").html(ui.draggable.html()).appendTo(this);
        ui.draggable.draggable({ disabled: true });
    }
});
```

This is the HTML that I want to drop to:

```
<div id="event">
   <div class="datatable clearboth">
        <table id="addLots" class="dataTable clearboth">
            <tr class="placeholder" style="width: 100%">
                <td style="height: 80px;">
                    Drag and drop rows here to add them to this event
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only your helper has the modified content, the original draggable still only contains the original draggable. You can try dumping the helper's contents into your new `<tr>`:

```
$("<tr></tr>").html(ui.helper.html()).appendTo(this);
```